# How to use angular2_material -dart and angular2-dart

Tags: angular, dart, angular2-forms

I found nine (9) angular2_material design implementation in beta-release at https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/angular2_material/src/components

However, there is no documentation as to how they should be used, although it is beta.

Could someone say how a simple input and a button can be seen using Dart and angular2-dart?

Also, there is no tag for angular2_material.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't much to use. Only a few elements were ported experimentally. There is a pub package angular2_material and the source you linked to should contain example code (maybe only TS, don't remember) but this is similar enough to Dart anyway. There is no documentation yet. 
I'm using `polymer_elements` for material design currently and it works well so far.

> However, there is no documentation as to how they should be used, although it is beta.

These elements are not part of Angular, they were added to the repository just for experimental purposes. "Beta" is not related to the material elements and the elements in the Angular repository and they will probably be dropped altogether.
**Update**
I saw it mentioned recently that angular_material2 accidently got the beta tag attached because all modules in the Angular2 repository were tagged beta, but that wasn't intended.
**Update end**

According to comments in GitHub issues, there is work in progress building Angular Material to Angular2.
The official repo to follow is https://github.com/angular/material2

Comment: You are using polymer_elements in polymer 1.0.rc.., NOT in angular2?

Comment: Actually I'm using polymer_elements in an Angular2 application but of course if have to use Polymer 1.0.rc.x as well otherwise the elements wouldn't work.